# Custom field and row separator in AWK (bash)

Tags: bash, awk

I have data in this order :

```
Person:Joe  
Age:24 
City:PH
---

Person:Joe 
Age:22  
City:NY
```

And i want to achieve data in this format

```
John|24|PH
Joe|22|NY
```

I tried with custom RS and OFS but i can't do this property.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: FS=":" ; RS="\n\n\n"

Comment: `awk -v RS='---'  '{$1=$1;gsub(/ Age:| City:/,"|");gsub(/Person:/,"")}1'`

Comment: Why did Joe become John?  Joe is short for Joseph.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'[:[:space:]]+' -v OFS='|' '{print $2, $4, $6}' file
Joe|24|PH
Joe|22|NY
```

Comment: Could you please add more explanation to your answer? Code only answers don't help learning very much for OP and others that will visit the question.

Comment: No, it's self-explanatory given a glance at the awk man page. Code-only answers help a great deal when they're this trivial and can be understood by a few minutes reading the man page which will give the reader far more insight than being spoon-fed this one small line of code. Did you have any specific questions?